# Writing React Component with multiple checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I have written his react component

```
  class RegistrationSpecialNeeds extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {"specialneeds": []}
        this.isChecked.bind(this)
     }
     handleChange(event, key) {
        console.log('came inside handle checkbox event')
        console.log('what is event ' + event.target.checked)
        console.log('what is key' + key)
     }
     isChecked(key) {
        if (this.state.specialneeds.indexOf(key) > -1) {true} else {false}
     }
     render() {
        return (
           <div>
           <label> check all that apply
              {
                 this.props.restrictions.map((restriction, index) => 
                    <div>
                    <label>
                       <input type='checkbox' name='restriction' checked={this.isChecked(restriction.key)} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, restriction.key)}/>{restriction.key}) {restriction.name}
                    </label>
                    </div>
                 )
              }
           </label>
           </div>
        )
     }
  }

<RegistrationSpecialNeeds restrictions={[{key: "a", name: "Dietary Restrictions"}, {key: 'b', name: 'Physical Disabilities'}, {key: 'c', name: 'Medical Needs'}]} />
```

When I select something in the checkbox I get output

[Log] came inside handle checkbox event (Registration.html, line 29)
[Log] what is event undefined (Registration.html, line 30)
[Log] what is keya (Registration.html, line 31)

how can I get the event object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the right way to pass the extra parameter which worked for me

```
onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, restriction.key)}
```

and the event handler looks like

```
 handleChange(event, key) {
   console.log('came inside handle checkbox event')
   console.log('what is event ' + event.target.checked)
   console.log('what is key' + key)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.props.restrictions.map((restriction, index) => 
                  <div>
                  <label>
                     <input type='checkbox' name='restriction' onChange={handleChange.bind(this, restriction.key)}/>{restriction.key}) {restriction.name}
                  </label>
                  </div>
               )
```

try to pass the value from input field and check the value in your `handleChange` method. use onChange attribute

Comment: `onChange(handleChange.bind(this, restriction.key))` doesn't provide the right parameters to the actual handleChange method. I did more googling and posted updated code above.